# Biot-Savart integral over a half-ellipse does not seem to approach the result on the line

Tags: potential, magnetostatics

I am trying to compute a Biot-Savart integral of the vector potential over one-half of an elliptic path, however as a check I compared the result when the ellipse becomes "squashed" as an approximation of the equivalent straight line, and to my chagrin and amusement, the results do not seem to match at all. My suspicion is that something is wrong in how I am evaluating the integrals

So, to evaluate the half-ellipse, I am parametrizing it as

$$ x = R_x \cos( \theta ) $$
$$ y = R_y \sin( \theta ) $$

Which has a line element:
$$ dl_x = -R_x \frac{ \sin( \theta ) }{ \sqrt{R_x^2 \sin^2( \theta) + R_y^2 \cos^2( \theta) } } $$
$$ dl_y = R_y \frac{ \cos( \theta ) }{ \sqrt{R_x^2 \sin^2( \theta) + R_y^2 \cos^2( \theta) } } $$

Let's focus only on the $y$ component: For the vector potential, this would be:

$$ A_y^{HE}(x,y) = R_y \int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}} { d \theta \frac{ \cos( \theta ) }{ \sqrt{R_x^2 \sin^2( \theta) + R_y^2 \cos^2( \theta) } \sqrt{(R_x \cos(\theta) - x)^2 + (R_y \sin(\theta) - y)^2 } } } $$

This represents a path from point $(0, R_y)$ to point $(0, -R_y)$. Now the straight path I am comparing this integral with would be a linear path:

$$ x = 0 $$
$$ y = R_y - 2 R_y \lambda $$

Which results in the following line integral:

$$ A_y^{SL}(x,y) = - \int_0^1{ d\lambda \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x^2 + (R_y - 2 R_y \lambda - y)^2 } } } $$

Now, my expectation is that $A_y^{HE}(x,y)$ would tend asymptotically to $A_y^{SL}(x,y)$ as $R_x \rightarrow 0$, I am evaluating the former one with `sympy`, but the results seem very different even for tiny values of $R_x$ (below $10^{-8}$). That seems fishy to me, unless either I am doing something wrong, or the integrals are expected to evaluate different even when the geometric paths seem arbitrarily close

**Edit** Values I am using for evaluating the integrals are $x=-5$, $y = 0$, $R_y = 1$ and values of $R_x$ between $10^{-3}$ and $10^{-8}$. For those values I am getting an asymptotic value of $A_y^{HE}(x=5,y=0) = -0.62217...$, while for the straight line integral I am getting $ A_y^{SL}(x=5,y=0)=-0.19869 $

Comment: Hello! "the results seem very different" -> where? The vector potential is defined in the whole space, if you go far enough from the wire then the two results should be indistinguishable. When you are within a few times $R_x$ from the wire, there you see differences.

Comment: @Quillo I've updated the question with concrete values, so the problem manifests with x values that are at least 3 orders of magnitude above $R_x$

Comment: Observation: the ratio of your two results is awfully close to π.

Comment: interesting! @MichaelSeifert but not sure how to account for it

Comment: @MichaelSeifert nice catch! UnkemptPanda: If this ratio is constant also at other points then it's just a missing factor!

Comment: nonetheless, the factor doesn't seem to approach $\pi$ either, it remains at $3.131373..$

Comment: btw, I tried with Wolfram Engine to discard a problem with `sympy` and the results seem consistent across the two CAS, so the problem seems to be on the integral formulation.. or my (our?) intuition about line integrals is off somehow

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with your parametrization in the elliptical case.  Let me think about it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral over the wire is parametrized incorrectly in both cases.  In both cases, your differential line element along the wire ($dl'$) is incorrect.

Using units where $\mu_0 = 4 \pi$, the general expression for $A_y$ is
$$
A_y(\vec{r}) = \int \frac{I'_y}{\mathscr{r}} \, dl' =I \int \frac{\hat{e}'_y}{\mathscr{r}} \, dl',
$$
where $\mathscr{r} \equiv |\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|$ and $\hat{e}$ is a unit vector pointing in the direction of the wire, and $dl'$ is the differential length element along the curve.  Importantly, this $dl'$ should correspond to the infinitesimal distance along the wire between two points separated by $d\theta$ (or, later, d$\lambda$.

In your notation, $dl_x$ and $dl_y$ are the components of $\hat{e}'$, so
$$
\hat{e}'_y = R_y \frac{ \cos( \theta ) }{ \sqrt{R_x^2 \sin^2( \theta) + R_y^2 \cos^2( \theta) } }.
$$
You have also correctly deduced that $\mathscr{r} = \sqrt{(R_x \cos(\theta) - x)^2 + (R_y \sin(\theta) - y)^2 }$.  But the differential line element should be
$$
dl' = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2} d\theta = \sqrt{R_x^2 \sin^2 \theta + R_y^2 \cos^2\theta} \, d\theta
$$
rather than just $d\theta$.  So the proper integral for the ellipse is
$$
A_y^{HE}(x,y) = R_y \int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}} { d \theta \frac{ \cos( \theta ) }{ \sqrt{(R_x \cos(\theta) - x)^2 + (R_y \sin(\theta) - y)^2 } } }
$$
(note the cancellation of one of the square root factors.)

Note that if we set $R_x = 0$ in this new integral and perform the substitution $1 - 2 \lambda = \sin \theta$, we obtain
$$
-2 R_y \int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda = 1} { d \lambda \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{x^2 + (R_y -2 \lambda R_y - y)^2 } } }.
$$
This agrees with your integral for the straight line except for the factor of 2 out front — but that's because your integral for the straight line also has the same sort of parametrization error in the line element; you should have $dl' = 2 \, d\lambda$, not $dl' = d \lambda$.

Comment: huh, I was adding the normalizing factor as I thought it was required to make the integral invariant to reparametrizations.. amusingly enough it seems that whatever parametrization one uses, doing it like you did will remove any normalizing factor.. however, I must say that both results now match. I don't understand why, as I thought this direct approach would have the result depend on the parametrization

Comment: @UnkemptPanda One way to see why the normalization factors cancel out is to note that $\vec{I} dl' = I d\vec{l}'$ at all points along the wire.  You used the first approach, which involves taking the $y$-component of $\vec{I}$ at each point in the wire. But you can also use the second approach, in which you treat $I$ as a constant and use $dl'_y$ (expressed appropriately in terms of your parameter, without worrying about the normalization) as your differential element.